# reverse engineering postgresql using hibernate tool in eclipse

Tags: hibernate-tools

I am trying to reverse engineer postgresql using hibernate tools in eclipse. It is not generating @Generated annotation.  postgres tables have primary key defined with serial keyword. what can be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You should modify the freemarker templates, and add someting like :

```
@${pojo.importType("javax.annotation.Generated")}(value = "Generated by Hibernate Tools ${version}", date = "${.now?iso_local}")
```

For JPA entities, you could add it in `pojo/PojoTypeDeclaration.ftl`

It works with Hibernate Tools 5.2.3 and Freemarker 2.3.23.

You could also add block comments like :

```
// Generated ${date} by Hibernate Tools ${version}
// and FreeMarker ${.version}
```